# SQL dynamic exec giving error that I already check for

Tags: sql, sql-server

THERE IS MORE CODE in the real code for example building up #Donelist that is not included in this code.

Column Fråga17 is the only that have values it this case.

In this I want to check if there column exists.

And if it exists it shall print out  the **counter** and **HÄR**.

And if it exists I shall check if there is any count on that column.

And if the value is over 0 it shall print out **DÄR** but I get an error that Fråga5 doesn't exist

I have even tried to use try catch before, IF EXISTS

Why does it show that the Fråga5 doesn't exist when it have checked before if it exists?

*In the real code I delete the column that don't have over 0. But this gives the same error*

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_TEMP_Temptable DROP COLUMN Fråga5


 PRINT 'PRINT4'

SET @RemoveColumnPart2COunter = 3
    
WHILE(@RemoveColumnPart2COunter <= 21)
BEGIN
    
PRINT @RemoveColumnPart2COunter
      
SET @RemoveColumnPart2 =
'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM x.information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = '+  CHAR(39)+'tbl_TEMP_Temptable'+  CHAR(39)+' AND COLUMN_NAME = '+  CHAR(39)+ 'Fråga'+@RemoveColumnPart2COunter +  CHAR(39)+') 
BEGIN
                        
print '  +CHAR(39) + @RemoveColumnPart2COunter+  ' HÄR'+CHAR(39)+'
                        
    
IF(   (SELECT COUNT(Fråga'+@RemoveColumnPart2COunter+') FROM dbo.tbl_TEMP_Temptable t INNER JOIN #Donelist d ON d.Utrustning = t.Utrustning) > 0 ) 
BEGIN
print '+CHAR(39)+' DÄR'+CHAR(39)+' 
END
END'

EXEC (@RemoveColumnPart2)
SET @RemoveColumnPart2COunter = @RemoveColumnPart2COunter + 1
END 

PRINT 'PRINT5'
```

-- I USE PRINT BECAUSE IT WILL SHOW ME WHERE THE ERROR IN
PRINT RESULT

```
PRINT4
3
3 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
4
4 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
5
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'Fråga5'.
6
6 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
7
7 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
8
8 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
9
9 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
10
10 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
11
11 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
12
12 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
13
13 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
14
14 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
15
15 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
16
16 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
17
17 HÄR
 DÄR
18
18 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
19
19 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
20
20 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
21
21 HÄR
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
PRINT5
```

If it execute the code it will do everything I want, still the will give error. But the Job agent in SQL Swrver will not finish the job it it will get errors and stop so I don't know it iy can go around this if I don't get an solution of the code. Like execure and ignore errors

*I might try to save the number and try to skip this number before it starts but its not a nice solution and I haven't tried it so I don't know if it will work still.*

Comment: Careful, that code looks *dangerously* open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server compiles your whole query, so if you have something that looks like:

```sql
if exists(
  select 1
  from sys.columns sc
  where sc.object_id = OBJECT_ID('sometable')
  and sc.name = 'someColumn')
BEGIN
   select soleColumn from someTable
END
```

It still validates if column exists when parsing the `select soleColumn from someTable`, since it needs to compile a proper query plan, leading to error.

Funnily enough, a table that *doesn't exists at all* doesn't get validated the same way, and will only crash if the `select ...` part is executed, it's called deferred name resolution.

I think you can probably simplify your code and move out the IF EXISTS part outside of dynamic sql, and leave the code that might fail in the dynamic SQL part. If you can't, you can wrap the "dangerous" code in another dynamic sql which then doesn't get any validation meaning it can pass

Answer (score 0):

Had an old version and just executed wrong and see that I didn't get error but it just keep writing out 5 so I set the counter up in the catch and then it worked. Weird that I just got this from open the wrong verison.

```
BEGIN try
                SET @RemoveColumnPart2 =
                    'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM x.information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = '+  CHAR(39)+'tbl_TEMP_Temptable'+  CHAR(39)+' AND COLUMN_NAME = '+  CHAR(39)+ 'Fråga'+@RemoveColumnPart2COunter +  CHAR(39)+') 
                    BEGIN

                    
                        IF(   (SELECT COUNT(Fråga'+@RemoveColumnPart2COunter+') FROM dbo.tbl_TEMP_Temptable t INNER JOIN #Donelist d ON d.Utrustning = t.Utrustning) > 0 ) 
                        BEGIN
                        ALTER TABLE tbl_TEMP_Temptable DROP COLUMN Fråga'+@RemoveColumnPart2COunter+'           
                        END
                    END'
                    EXEC (@RemoveColumnPart2)
                    SET @RemoveColumnPart2COunter = @RemoveColumnPart2COunter + 1
                    END TRY
                    BEGIN CATCH
                    SET @RemoveColumnPart2COunter = @RemoveColumnPart2COunter + 1
                    END CATCH
```